# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:dokka'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-dokka

I'm trying to use dokka on my android project to generate kdoc.
But I have this error when I'm running the script 'modules:app [dokka]' :
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:dokka'.
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException (no error message)

I added the following lines on my gradle files :

Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        dokka_version = '0.9.18'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:$dokka_version"
    }
}
```

app build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'
}
dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    sourceDirs = files('src/main')
    outputDirectory = "$buildDir/javadoc"
}
```

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:dokka'.
>   kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: `apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'` ???

Comment: nope. And i'm already using gradle plugins dsl syntax : plugins { id ...}

Comment: I think you need to explicitly tell Gradle what version to use: `id 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android' version '0.9.18'

Comment: the version is already in the classpath, so no need to explicitly tell the version when applying the plugin

Comment: I don't know if it has some impact but it's a multi module project, and there's a multiplatform ios/android module in addition to the android app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that it's a multiplatform project. In the app level gradle file, I'm also applying the `org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform` plugin. As described in the [dokka github release page](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/releases):

`Experimental Kotlin Multiplatform support is scheduled for 0.9.19`

Looks like there's no other solution than wait for the next release of dokka.

**Edit:** There's a workaround described [on the kolinlang forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-configure-dokka-for-kotlin-multiplatform/9834)

```
dokka {
    impliedPlatforms = ["common"] // This will force platform tags for all non-common sources e.g. "JVM"
    kotlinTasks {
        // dokka fails to retrieve sources from MPP-tasks so they must be set empty to avoid exception
        // use sourceRoot instead (see below)
        []
    }
    sourceRoot {
        // assuming there is only a single source dir...
        path = kotlin.sourceSets.commonMain.kotlin.srcDirs[0]
        platforms = ["common"]
    }
}
```